# Collapse all Visual Studio toolbox regions shortcut

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-macros

Is there a keyboard shortcut or macro to collapse all regions in Visual Studio's toolbox?  (Failing either of those, I'll take an addin that allows this!)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

While the focus is on the toolbox, press <kbd>/</kbd> to Collapse All.

You can also Expand All by pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>

Here's an article by Sarah Ford with more information: **[Visual Studio Tip #186](http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2008/04/03/did-you-know-you-can-use-to-expand-all-and-to-collapse-all-in-the-toolbox-186.aspx)**

**BEFORE:**

[image]
<sub>(source: [msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/saraford/WindowsLiveWriter/Did.YoucanusetoExpandAllandtoCollapseAll_DF23/ToolboxAllExpanded_thumb.jpg))</sub>

**AFTER:**

[image]
<sub>(source: [msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/saraford/WindowsLiveWriter/Did.YoucanusetoExpandAllandtoCollapseAll_DF23/ToolboxAllCollapsed_thumb.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Funny how they didn't add that to the context menu of the panel

Comment: Checking in almost 5 years later to say thanks :) So silly that there isn't just a button or context menu to do this... What an arbitrary shortcut. Works in VS2010

Comment: +1 Wow, that's it! Super time saver. We have over 30 of those and they always expand by default. Until 5 minutes ago, I was collapsing each of them manually. Thanks!

Comment: Got tired of collapsing them all manually and did a search to see if there was a shortcut. Much appreciated, thanks so much!

Comment: we are in 2015 and the question is still relevant, how sad for MS.

Comment: +1 - Finally found it! Thanks, "/" worked for me in VS 2013. "Shift + 8" doesn't work but "*" works for "Expand All".

Comment: Your jpg links appear to be broken. Looks like MS removed them.

Comment: This is true in VS 2017 AND there's still no obvious way if you don't know or hunt for this answer LOL.

Comment: Still needed to look this up in 2022, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> is your friend.

Also see Window>Auto Hide All

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that gives full screen mode on my rig (VS2008) - I'm after a region collapse in the toolbox.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I did some legwork and couldn't find anything. :\ Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't see anything out there either.  Thanks for trying!